# Passing arguments, good and bad practice in Java/OOP programming

Tags: java, oop, methods, arguments

I've recently started writing android applications in Java, I'm completely new to Java and I did the basics of object oriented programming in c++ at college.
 My question is, what is good and bad practice when passing variable data to different methods in Java? For example, something I have been doing in my code is:

```
String one;
String two;
String three;
String four;

exampleOne(one, two, three, four);

exampleOne(String one, String two, String three, String four) {
      // do something
      exampleTwo(one, two, three, four);
}

exampleTwo(String one, String two, String three, String four) {
      // do something
      exampleThree(one, two, three, four);
}

exampleThree(String one, String two, String three, String four) {
      // do something
}
```

In my code I've done something like this where I pass arguments up to 5 times, is it bad practice to do this? What would be a cleaner more eco option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are many arguments and they would be passed many times, I would go for a DTO object.

Create a Pojo class which encapsulates those parameters and pass the instance between methods. You can add some helper functions/methods in the DTO as well, to ease some processing.

Comment: great idea, that would make things a lot cleaner and easier

Answer (score 2):

It could be useful to declare a class like this:

```
public class YourClass{

    private String one;
    private String two;
    private String three;
    private String four;

    public YourClass(String one, String two, String three, String four){
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
        this.three = three;
        this.four= four;
    }

    public void exampleOne() {
          // do something
          exampleTwo();
    }

    public void exampleTwo() {
          // do something
          exampleThree();
    }

    public void exampleThree() {
          // do something
    }

}
```

And use it:

```
YourClass c = new YourClass(one, two, three, four);
c.exampleOne();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,Passing Argument is required when ever you want to call method with some attributes but for huge number of arguments of Same type you can use following.

You can use `VarArgs` instead.

```
public void Method(String.. str) {
   //Here you will have Array  str[](Of String)  
  if(str!=null)
   for (String s: str) 
    System.out.println(s);//Iterate through Array for More Processing

}
```

---

If you want to Pass Other Argument as well

```
 Method(int i, String... Other) {
    //VarArgs Must be Last
  }
```

---

*NOTE:*
Pass Arguments of Different type and Use conversion methods to convert String to Double,Int,etc.*(well This is not recommended but can be done because you need to make sure at which place you have passed double,int etc.)*

Comment: What if you're passing arguments of a different type?

Comment: this could be handy, but sometimes it is in-convenient because you have to retrieve each element in array way.

Comment: @Kent Yes Agree!!But as OP has stated this method I can say more convenient than OP's code.

Comment: check for `str != null` too as per when the method is called without parameters, otherwise you'll get a npe (NullPointerException)

Comment: @TAsk I didn't mean your answer is in-convenient. It depends on the requirement. Many frameworks use it too, E.g. when you pass parameter value to a sql query, or print log with some argument etc. However it could be in-convenient in two sides, 1) the method caller has to prepare the array carefully, in terms of the sequence order; 2) the method callee has to get the value by index and (probably) with  type casting

Comment: @Kent YES I agree and at for both 1 and 2 Programmer need to work carefully otherwise it may lead to tears sometimes.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in what you did but you can clarify things up using varargs (as TAsk stated) or by creating a small container class (like a c struct, often called bean) which represents a set of parameters.

This allows you to tidy things and make code more readable.
Please be aware that when creating a class you will introduce a little overhead due to a new allocation while this wasn't true with c-struct as it is the compiler which manage references to struct members.

Parameters are passed in stack like in c and there is no concept of by-reference-arguments in java, using a bean can overcome this limitation.

Comment: That's good to know, something about passing arguments several times just doesn't feel like a very clean way of doing things